# symfony2: how to use points instead of comma for decimals separator while keeping fr locale

Tags: php, symfony, numbers, decimal, locale

In Symfony 2, with a french default locale, there are some cases when decimal values separator are rendered as commas in forms.

Commas in forms are not always converted to points which is the separator used by my database.

How can I make sure every numeric data field comma is replaced by a point after form sumission?

I found the `NumberToLocalizedStringTransformer`:

[This reference](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/5941) but do I need to add a datatransformer to every form to make it work as I wish ?

Comment: Does my answer not provide a solution to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a DataTransformer is one approach to solving your localization problem. You don't need to add it to every form. You can create your own FormType extending or inheriting the (I guess) `number` type. Within your own form type add the transformer with a call to `FormBuilderInterface::addViewTranformer()`.

You can find more [information here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html). Here is an example from one of my own custom types. Using this method you are also able to customize the widget used for rendering.

```
class CustomType extends NumberType
{        
    public function buildForm ( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        parent::buildForm( $builder, $options );

        $builder->addViewTransformer( new CustomTransformer() );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'my_custom_type';
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use your localized numbers build your form with a `my_custom_type` instead of `number`.

Another solution would be to force your users to use points by showing an error if they use anything else. [Look here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html) for Symfony form validation. The `Regex` validator with something like `/^(\d|\.)+$/` would work.

Comment: that's indeed what I ended up doing but I was hoping ther was a more general way of handling this